# Unit Testing ActiveX Control (C++)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, atl

I'm having trouble finding information on this through Google, so figured I'd ask here.

I have an ActiveX control developed in C++ with ATL.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012.  I want to add unit tests to this project.

I'm not sure what to do to get started, frankly.  I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use a native or managed test project, I've tried both.  But I can't even figure out how to instantiate the control within the test code to begin testing it.  Does anyone know of some basic documentation or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385(v=vs.120).aspx

Also there are a lot of good projects on code project go through them.

To break out any ATL dependencies you should refactor your code in a separate lib or dll, or another option would be to link to the object file generated.

HTH